# File Quarantined by Anti-Virus Software from the Latest Upgrade of Tor Browser

Tags: security, firefox, tor-install, update, firewall

I upgraded to the lastest version of Tor browser 9.0, and my antivirus software [360 Safeguard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/360_Safeguard) reported the file nssdbm3.dll being infected by trojan win32/Trojan.7be

Could anybody tell me if this is a false positive or is it really a threat?

So far my Tor browser works well. It seems that there is no need to run nssdbm3.dll.

Could any experts explain to me why this can happen to Tor browser? Thank you very much.